# Why Internet Explorer fires OnQuit event on navigation even though IE doesn't quit?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, events, browser, automation

There's the following code:

```
Dim InternetExplorer As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
InternetExplorer.Visible = True

InternetExplorer.
    Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/")

AddHandler InternetExplorer.OnQuit,
    Sub()
        Console.WriteLine("InternetExplorer.OnQuit")
    End Sub
```

When I run the code under Internet Explorer 11

1. Internet Explorer opens
2. Internet Explorer navigates to `http://stackoverflow.com/` page

If then I click `Questions` button

1. `OnQuit` event fires and console writes `InternetExplorer.OnQuit`
2. But page with questions `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` successfully loads

If then I navigate back and click `Questions` button again `OnQuit` event doesn't fire, but Internet Explorer loses all event subscriptions.

[OnQuit event fires before the Windows Internet Explorer application quits.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768340(v=vs.85).aspx)

1. How is it possible that IE fires `OnQuit` event on navigation even though IE doesn't quit?
2. Why does IE lose all event subscriptions when page changes?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same problem. Our workaround is a massive pile of hacks to try keeping track of which InternetExplorer instances correspond to live tabs and which don't.